# MySQL random m out of n selection

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have a list of students and I want to do a simple query like:

```
SELECT * FROM STUDENTS WHERE SCHOOLID = 10;
```

However, If there are like 20(or n) students in school 10, I'd like to randomly choose 7(or m) students each time I run the query. Is there a possible query in MySQL for this?

Comment: Well thanks a lot arxanas, solved my issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
SELECT * FROM students WHERE schoolid = 10 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT m
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM STUDENTS WHERE SCHOOLID = 10 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 7
```

Please mind using `RAND()` is bad practice for big tables.

Answer (score 1):

You could try (EDIT: oops, TOP is a T-SQL keyword; Oracle/MySQL use LIMIT):

```
SELECT * FROM STUDENTS WHERE SCHOOLID=10 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 7
```

Comment: Oops.. it's mysql not mssql :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `LIMIT m` to select only m results, and `ORDER BY RAND()` to randomize the m records you select:

```
SELECT * FROM Students
WHERE SchoolID = 10
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 7
```